# Error "Index was outside the bounds of the array." When save excel file VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net

I'm trying to copy worksheet excel to new workbook and save that, but i'm get an error "Index was outside the bounds of the array." .. Here my code :

```
Try
            Dim dt As DataTable = ClsUploadBreakDownInquiryDB.GetFinalInspectionData(pProjectNo, pOrderNo)

            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                ExcelMenu = dt.Rows(0).Item("BOM_ID")
                filelocation = Server.MapPath("~/FinalInspection/" + ExcelMenu + ".xlsx")

                exl_a = New Excel.Application
                exl_a.DisplayAlerts = False

                '# Open saved excel file for modification...
                exl_b1 = exl_a.Workbooks.Open(filelocation)

                '# Create new workbook...
                exl_b2 = exl_a.Workbooks.Add()

                Dim IColumn() As String = {"W", "H", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4"}
                Dim Cells() As String = {"Project Name", "Project No.", "Item No.", "Unit Code", "Colour", "QTY", "W", "H", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4"}
                Dim Proceed As Boolean = False

                xlWorkSheets = exl_b2.Sheets
                'Create Sheet
                For irow = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

                    ExcelMenu = dt.Rows(irow).Item("BOM_ID")
                    filelocation = Server.MapPath("~/FinalInspection/" + ExcelMenu + ".xlsx")

                    exl_b3 = exl_a.Workbooks.Open(filelocation)
                    exl_s = exl_b3.ActiveSheet

                    '# Copy the 1st sheet from saved excel to new workbook...
                    exl_s.Copy(Before:=exl_b2.Worksheets(1))

                    exl_s = exl_b2.Worksheets(1)
                    exl_s.Name = dt.Rows(irow).Item("ITEM_NO")


                    For Each CellData As String In Cells

                        ' Get the WorkSheet to search on
                        For x As Integer = 1 To xlWorkSheets.Count
                            xlWorkSheet = CType(xlWorkSheets(x), Excel.Worksheet)

                            If xlWorkSheet.Name = exl_s.Name Then
                                Proceed = True
                                Exit For
                            End If

                            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet)
                            xlWorkSheet = Nothing

                        Next

                        ' WorkSheet was located so search for text.
                        If Proceed Then
                            If CellData.Contains(IColumn.ToString()) Then
                                xlTargetRange = xlWorkSheet.Range("I" & "1")
                            Else
                                xlTargetRange = xlWorkSheet.Range("B" & "1")
                            End If

                            Result = xlTargetRange.Find(
                                CellData,
                                ,
                                Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
                                Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole,
                                Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
                                Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
                                False
                            )

                            If Result IsNot Nothing Then
                                FoundRow = Result.Row
                                FoundColum = Result.Column + 1
                                Dim xlCells As Excel.Range = Nothing
                                xlCells = xlWorkSheet.Range("B" & FoundRow.ToString)
                                FoundValue = CStr(xlCells.Value)
                                If Not xlCells Is Nothing Then
                                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlCells)
                                    xlCells = Nothing
                                End If

                                'function for fill cell data based on array Cells()
                                If CellData = "Project Name" Then
                                    exl_s.Cells(FoundRow, FoundColum) = dt.Rows(irow).Item("PROJECT_NAME")
                                ElseIf CellData = "Project No." Then
                                    exl_s.Cells(FoundRow, FoundColum) = dt.Rows(irow).Item("PROJECT_NO")
                                ElseIf CellData = "Item No." Then
                                    exl_s.Cells(FoundRow, FoundColum) = dt.Rows(irow).Item("ITEM_NO")
                                ElseIf CellData = "Unit Code" Then
                                    exl_s.Cells(FoundRow, FoundColum) = dt.Rows(irow).Item("Unit_Code")
                                ElseIf CellData = "Colour" Then
                                    exl_s.Cells(FoundRow, FoundColum) = dt.Rows(irow).Item("COLOR_CODE")
                                ElseIf CellData = "QTY" Then
                                    exl_s.Cells(FoundRow, FoundColum) = dt.Rows(irow).Item("Qty")
                                ElseIf CellData = "W" Then
                                    exl_s.Cells(FoundRow, FoundColum) = dt.Rows(irow).Item("Width")
                                ElseIf CellData = "H" Then
                                    exl_s.Cells(FoundRow, FoundColum) = dt.Rows(irow).Item("height")
                                ElseIf CellData = "h1" Then
                                    exl_s.Cells(FoundRow, FoundColum) = dt.Rows(irow).Item("Height_1")
                                ElseIf CellData = "h2" Then
                                    exl_s.Cells(FoundRow, FoundColum) = dt.Rows(irow).Item("Height_2")
                                ElseIf CellData = "h3" Then
                                    exl_s.Cells(FoundRow, FoundColum) = dt.Rows(irow).Item("Height_3")
                                ElseIf CellData = "h4" Then
                                    exl_s.Cells(FoundRow, FoundColum) = dt.Rows(irow).Item("Height_4")
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If

                    Next

                    exl_b3.Close()

                Next

                'Delete Unused WorkSheet
                Dim ExcelSheet As Integer = dt.Rows.Count
                exl_a.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                For iSheet = 1 To exl_a.Sheets.Count - ExcelSheet
                    exl_a.Sheets("Sheet" + iSheet.ToString()).Delete()
                Next
                exl_a.Application.DisplayAlerts = True


                Dim user As String = System.Environment.UserName
                Dim user2 As String = GetUserName()
                exl_b2.SaveAs("C:\Users\" & user & "\Downloads\" & pProjectNo & "_" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Format(Date.Now, "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") & ".xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook)


                '# Show print preview...
                exl_a.Visible = True


                '# To properly KILL excel process...
                releaseObject(exl_a)
                releaseObject(exl_b1)
                releaseObject(exl_b2)
                releaseObject(exl_s)

                exl_a = Nothing
                exl_b1 = Nothing
                exl_b2 = Nothing
                exl_s = Nothing

                GC.GetTotalMemory(False)
                GC.Collect()
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
                GC.Collect()
                GC.GetTotalMemory(True)

                CountData = 1

            End If

            Return CountData
            '# End

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Error: " & ex.Message)
            If Not IsNothing(exl_b1) Then exl_b1.Close(False)
            If Not IsNothing(exl_b2) Then exl_b2.Close(False)
            exl_a.Quit()

        End Try
```

In my local running success, but when i'm publish my code and running that then i get an error.. What should i do? Where's the wrong syntax ? Thanks you before

I'm already running in lokal and success, can't debug this error because published file

Comment: You're trying to access an element in one of the arrays where there isn't an element. Look at all the places in your code where you loop through arrays, and it'll be there somewhere. Often .count return the count, not the ordinal indexes, so for count of 2, you should be looking at indexes 0 and 1 etc.

Comment: At which row you get the error? I would susopect at `For iSheet = 1 To exl_a.Sheets.Count - ExcelSheet`.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer will it be an error when i try to access a value from an array that doesn't exist in the excel worksheet ? for count of 2, i want to start from first data , so i can get the value of BOM_ID

Comment: @Arvo the error message appears in the catch line, so I'm not sure where the error lies, in the ` For iSheet ` i want delete default Worksheet

Comment: You have heard something about debugging, yes, no? Look at the pointed line - you are subtracting rows count from sheet number. Does not seem like proper action to me.

Comment: If you're going to delete something in a loop like this, you have to count backwards.  For iSheet = exl_a.Sheets.Count - ExcelSheet to 1 Step -1

Comment: @Arvo i know about debugging, but in this case i'm running my publish code so i can't debug my code

Comment: i think my problem isn't in excel worksheet looping because when i'm delete this looping, i still get an error like above

Comment: I Found the problem, 
`Dim user2 As String = GetUserName()`
I don't understand why this line give me an error